# Failed to open stream but this time its class-wp-rewrite.php

Tags: wordpress

> Warning:
> require(/home/tbc5pvfk36ns/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/tbc5pvfk36ns/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 202
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/home/tbc5pvfk36ns/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php'
> (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in
> /home/tbc5pvfk36ns/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 202 There has
> been a critical error on this website.

It was a fresh godaddy wordpress install, it was working fine until this happened out of nowhere.